# Retrieve data based on year and month in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to create a get statements function and I have some problems defining the date range.

The data will be passed via get method in the following format: **?year=yyyy&month=mm** 
The relevant column of the table has **datetime** type (**2012-02-01**).

I checked the **TimeHelper** class and more particularly the `TimeHelper::daysAsSql($begin, $end, $fieldName, $timezone = NULL)` but i am not sure if it applies for this case.

I was thinking if i can create a date in the format of Y-m using the two variables year and month and then use it in the conditions for retrieving the data but I am sure there is a more efficient and proper way. Could anyone help?

```
$user_id = $Client['Client']['id'];
    $year = $this->request['url']['year'];
    $month = $this->request['url']['month'];
    //$date_created = date('Y-m');


  if (!empty($user_id) && (!empty($date_created))) {


        $Reports = $this->Report->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('amount','currency','date_created','invoice_no'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Report.client_id'=> $user_id,
            'Report.date_created >=' => $date_created, 
            'Report.date_created <=' => $date_created

             ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: Based on the conditions in your sample, it will only work if Report.date_created is equal to $date_created. Because it can't be smaller than, AND bigger at the same time. Did you mean to have other conditions, like date_start and date_end in there?

Answer (score 1):

**MONTH**(dateColumn) Returns an integer that represents the month of the specified date.

**YEAR**(dateColumn)  Returns an integer that represents the year of the specified date.

InCakephp use as

```
$user_id = $Client['Client']['id'];
    $year = $this->request['url']['year'];
    $month = $this->request['url']['month'];
    //$date_created = date('Y-m');


    if (!empty($user_id) && (!empty($date_created))) {


        $Reports = $this->Report->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array('amount','currency','date_created','invoice_no'),
                'conditions' => array(
                        'Report.client_id '=> $user_id,
                        'MONTH(date_created ) >='=> $month,
                        'YEAR(date_created ) <=' => $year

                ),
        )
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful.  So using MONTH and YEAR from the date column can i write some like in cakephp?

SELECT * FROM `Report` WHERE strftime('%m', `date_created`) = $month AND strftime('%y', `date_created`) =year

Comment: STRFTIME() in SQLite is similar to DATE_FORMAT() in MySQL with reversed parameters.
Since %d and %m map to the same thing in both, your expression can simply be written as;
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_created, '%m') = .......